# How do I cryptanalyze a password field?

Tags: cryptanalysis, passwords

In a PostgreSQL database, I can see the following fields in a table (for a specific record):

User = administrator
Password = "ceMv9Me6go"

Now the following are true:

- The password length is not fixed, thus I'm leaning towards it being an
  encryption rather than a hash.
- The actual password is "password"
- Salt is unknown (if at all used)

What steps should I take to learn what algorithm might have been used? How could I break the cryptography (assuming it is cryptographically protected) to recover the master password?

Comment: From the information you have given, I think the best advice you can give your customer is to switch applications. It is highly likely given the details you've provided that the password storage is not very secure. Makes you wonder what other mistakes the developers made.

Comment: For christ sake, this is part of a vendor solution that encompasses the entire UC deployment over several sites, not to mention the dozens of other clients who utilse the same application as well. I've tried on stackoverflow, and was recommended to put the question here. "Recommend the customer another application" is NOT and I repeat NOT an acceptable reason to close this question. The security of the storage of the password is completely out of scope of this request, all I want is for someone to have a crack at some various encryption algorithms and see if one matches the above password.

Comment: The question was not closed because of my suggestion. It was closed because requests to analyze or decrypt data are off topic. See the FAQ. The stackoverflow folks warned you this might happen if you go back there and read the comments. I'd suggest you look at the FAQ for what is on topic and edit the question to make it on topic, then we might be able to help.

Comment: Since you know one plaintext/ciphertext pair, here are a few questions that if I were trying to figure it out I would want to know. Is the ciphertext deterministic for a single user? Is it deterministic across multiple users? You say the lengths are not the same. Do same length passwords have same length corresponding "ciphertexts"?

Comment: Continued: is there an obvious block length? In other words, do the sizes of all ciphertexts have some common multiple (like 40 bits or 80 bits). If you can access many, many ciphertexts, what is the entropy? If the entropy isn't high, it might be an encoding scheme instead of encryption.

Comment: As mike suggested, try decoding with various schemes. The appearance of the characters makes me think it might be base64, so glue an == to the end and try decoding it with a tool. Is there anything in the resulting bytes that lead you to a conclusion? Is it the same number of bytes as the password itself? Does it XOR with other passwords to yield a common stream you can factor out?

Comment: I took the liberty of rewriting the question into a more acceptable form, and voted to reopen. @mikeazo would you agree?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would want to know is if the encoding is deterministic. This should be easy to test. Change the password, but make it the same value. If the value in the DB doesn't change, then it is deterministic. Also try this for a few users. Give them all the same password and see if the DB entries are the same.

If so, you don't really even need to reverse the process. Just write down a DB password value to which you know the corresponding password. If the customer forgets the password, change the DB entry to the known value and they can get back in. If it is not deterministic you may still be able to do this.

From there, operating under the assumption that it is crypto, I would try to see how password length affects DB value length. Are all DB value lengths a multiple of some value? If so you might have your block length. There could be some encoding (base64) though, so that could play into it too.

To get an idea as to whether or not it is crypto protecting the DB you could test the entropy of a number of DB values.

If all else fails, reverse engineer the application.

Comment: Thanks Mike, appreciate the input; will test and see what happens.